# Parsing through JSON data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am not experienced with JSON. I'm using https://www.zipcodeapi.com/ to try to determine zipcodes within a radius. I can't seem to show the response here but attached is what my console log is showing.

I'm trying to grab the zip code and store it in an array but I'm not having any luck doing it. When i tried a test JSON site everything did seem to work fine. Here's the code I'm using:

```
                }).done(function(data){
        
        console.log(data); <-- prints what you see in the attached inspector pic
        //reset previous lookup
        zip_codes = [];
                    
        $.each(data, function(index,e){
          zip_codes.push(e.zip_code); <-- does nothing
        });
      });
```

[image: inspect screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `data` variable here is an object and not an array. Here array is `data.zip_codes`, so you should be doing

```
    $.each(data.zip_codes, function(index,e){
       zip_codes.push(e.zip_code); // will do this time :)
    });
```